# css keyframe left 100% top 100% weird behavior

Tags: html, css

So basically I am trying to make a box go around the border of the parent with CSS, it works well if I only specify percentage value to either top or left, something like

```
@keyframes mymove {
    0%   {top: 0px; left: 0px; background: red;}
    25%  {top: 0px; left: 100%; background: blue;}
    50%  {top: 100px; left: 100%; background: yellow;}
    75%  {top: 100px; left: 0px; background: green;}
    100% {top: 0px; left: 0px; background: red;}
}
```

but it animates very weird if I do

```
@keyframes mymove {
        0%   {top: 0px; left: 0px; background: red;}
        25%  {top: 0px; left: 100%; background: blue;}
        50%  {top: 100%; left: 100%; background: yellow;}
        75%  {top: 100%; left: 0px; background: green;}
        100% {top: 0px; left: 0px; background: red;}
    }
```

the box got to the far right and then stopped there for 0.5 sec and then back to far right without going to the bottom. And then it jumped to the bottom at left=0px and came back up. You can see the result yourself, kind of hard to explain.

jsfiddler:
http://jsfiddle.net/jzawddLc/
http://jsfiddle.net/jqytraL7/

Running on IE 11 if that is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set `100%` **height to `html, body`**!
- Account a negative margin to the box position

```css
html, body{ height:100%; }
body{margin:0;} /* if needed... */

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes mymove {
    0%   {top: 0; left: 0; background: red;}
    25%  {top: 0; left: 100%;     margin:0 -100px; background: blue;}
    50%  {top: 100%; left: 100%;  margin:-100px;   background: yellow;}
    75%  {top: 100%; left: 0;     margin:-100px 0; background: green;}
    100% {top: 0px; left: 0;      margin: 0;        background: red;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Alternatively, instead of `100%` if it's really the window size you're interested in (not an  parent-inherited size) you can go for **Viewport unit**:

```
@keyframes mymove {
  0%   {top: 0; left: 0; background: red;}
  25%  {top: 0; left: calc(100vw - 100px); background: blue;}
  50%  {top: calc(100vh - 100px); left: calc(100vw - 100px); background: yellow;}
  75%  {top: calc(100vh - 100px); left: 0; background: green;}
  100% {top: 0px; left: 0; background: red;}
}
```

Comment: I want it to go around the border..not just up and down, if I apply the calc(100%-100px) to both top and left then it just wont move anymore

Comment: @Steve, yes, it will if you set `html, body{ height:100%;}` in your CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/jzawddLc/3/

Comment: IE 11 supports the latest css3 I believe, it works if I only specify percentage value to left, not top. (which means I shouldn't need -ms- )

Comment: @Steve weird weird. IE sucks like always. Edited my answer with a crossbrowser (newer browsers ;) ) solution

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare the start position of the box on the element.

//HTML BLOCK

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

//CSS BLOCK

```
#parent{
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}
#child{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    background:blue;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 10s infinite; 
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0%   {top: 0%; left: 0%; background: red;}
    25%  {top: 0%; left: 50%; background: blue;}
    50%  {top: 50%; left: 50%; background: yellow;}
    75%  {top: 50%; left: 0%; background: green;}
    100% {top: 0%; left: 0%; background: orange;}
}
```

Comment: well like I said, I have no problem getting it to move if I use pixel as unit, but when I start using 100% it just won't work

Comment: Declare % instead of px on the actual id (#child) then change all the other animations to %. Use 50% not 100%, you just have to keep consistency of units throughout it. I just updated my code to show you.

Comment: thx for the input, unfortunately this doesn't work with IE (even after I remove -webkit-) I think this is a bug in IE, but the solution provided by Roko works great

Comment: It works on IE 10+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes... but as long as you got it working with Roko's then all good.

Comment: The css property is supported, but the outcome is not ideal..yep..IE sux as always LOL